# What's better: enter or input?

Tags: word-choice, headlinese

Some time ago I've been showing my computer program to my teacher. Suddenly he began to laugh pointing at *'Please enter your name: '* statement. I tried to figure out what was wrong. He said it's better to use *input* instead of *enter* and the sentence sounds funny otherwise.

[Here](http://www.yourdictionary.com/input) they're defining the word *input* using the word *enter*.

> To *enter* data into the computer.

What's better to use in such sentences as *'Please (input/enter) your name: '* - *input* or *enter*?

Comment: If anything, 'input' sounds a bit over-technical! Your teacher was **wrong** (which proves that they are mere humans after all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy-to-use computer programs tend to have very short user instructions.  Short prompts are often better than polite prompts.

Joel Spolsky (our host) has written [an article about this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000062.html).  Scroll down to the part that has the pictures, titled "In fact, users don't read *anything*."

In the original poster's example, I would label the text entry box as
Name:

Comment: That is true. We/They read nothing (nothing includes mainly tos).

Answer (score 3):

I write software, and would always use "Please enter your name:"  There's nothing funny sounding about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a key **Enter** on your keyboard.

In the past, when graphical interface was not so popular, people hit the Enter key after typing a command or an answer to the computer.  So *Enter your username* actually asked you to hit the Enter key after your key-ins.

Nowadays, however, you use a mouse or hit the Tab key to jump to the next textbox.  So I believe, using **Input** would avoid misleading the users to hit the Enter key.  For example, on a web page, hitting the Enter key actually submits the input form on the page.